# Issues with merging multiple dataframes (with varying rows) using a common column

Tags: r

Suppose I have many data frames, that have varying row numbers (of data) but Date as common among them. e.g. :

DF1:

```
Date        Index      Change
05-04-17    29911.55    0
03-04-17    29910.22    0.0098
31-03-17    29620.5     -0.0009
30-03-17    29647.42    0.0039
29-03-17    29531.43    0.0041
28-03-17    29409.52    0.0059
27-03-17    29237.15    -0.0063
24-03-17    29421.4     0.003
```

And

DF2:

```
Date    NG  NG_Change
05-04-17    213.8   0.0047
04-04-17    212.8   0.0421
03-04-17    204.2   -0.0078
31-03-17    205.8   -0.0068
30-03-17    207.2   -0.0166
29-03-17    210.7   0.0483
28-03-17    201 0.005
27-03-17    200 -0.0015
24-03-17    200.3   0.0137
```

And another one:

DF3:

```
Date       TI_Price TI_Change
05-04-17    51.39   0.0071
04-04-17    51.03   0.0157
03-04-17    50.24   -0.0071
31-03-17    50.6    0.005
30-03-17    50.35   0.017
29-03-17    49.51   0.0236
28-03-17    48.37   0.0134
```

I wanted to combine them, using Dates column "as common variable", in a way that there are only those rows in the final for which Dates are common. Such as:

```
Date    TI_Price    TI_Change   NG  NG_Change   TI_Price    TI_Change
05-04-17    51.39   0.0071      213.8   0.0047  51.39       0.0071
04-04-17    51.03   0.0157      212.8   0.0421  51.03       0.0157
03-04-17    50.24   -0.0071     204.2   -0.0078 50.24       -0.0071
31-03-17    50.6    0.005       205.8   -0.0068 50.6        0.005
30-03-17    50.35   0.017       207.2   -0.0166 50.35       0.017
29-03-17    49.51   0.0236      210.7   0.0483  49.51       0.0236
28-03-17    48.37   0.0134  201 0.005   48.37   0.0134
```

I am just wondering if there is any method so that I could merge them in one go and not like the merge() function which takes DF2 and DF2 at a time, merge and then the result is merged with DF3.

What I used and tweaked around (but waste):

```
 myfulldata = merge(DF1, DF2, all.x=T)
```

Comment: `Reduce(merge, list(df1, df2, df3))`

Comment: @RonakShah I already tried that one. It will creat a list and I need a dataframe. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It gives dataframe as output to me.

Comment: @MadhuSareen If you already tried that method, you should include it as something you tried in your original post. That way, the above conversation doesn't happen. Second, does the method work for you for the above example data, but fail on your real data? In that instance, you have to provide an example that reproduces your problem. ronak-shah's suggestion produced a data.frame for me.